# Как разместить изображение в layout в android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.111clock);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Ничего не происходит код проглатывает но ничего не происходит даже после ребилда

Как это сделать при помощи вкладки Design/Text я понимаю, но почему не проходит через джава код не пойму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас дважды назначается разметка для активити.

В первый раз вы устанавливаете картинку, после чего заново всю разметку загружаете и картинку заново не назначаете, вот её и не видно.

Вам надо убрать второй вызов метода установки разметки активити

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```